# CSS <div> styling

Tags: css, html, styling

http://jsfiddle.net/Zmpyv/6/

I have a page, where I use `<div>` to style the sheet. The problem is that it creates a border around the page. How can I remove this border? Check out the jsfiddle to see what I mean. I am using position: static; I do not want to use fixed because then the page won't scroll correctly.

Comment: A `<div>` takes up full width by default, `position: fixed;` makes it stay in place when you scroll. That said, it's hard to tell what you want the end result to be. Please also include the relevant code in your question, for posterity.

Comment: @xec Ohh that was never explained to me... If you look at the class 'space' you will notice that it is the width of the page, but it has a white border on each side. How would I solve this?

Comment: @xec Yes! That solved it, I had asked about that on SO before, and they all told me to use position: fixed;. <.< Thank You sooo much. If you make that an answer I'll select it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you're just talking about the native `margin` on `<body>`. Try this;

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Check out http://jsfiddle.net/Zmpyv/8 where I added the above CSS to your demo.

To avoid spending time fighting silly things like this, I recommend you have a look at [normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css) which applies this style for you, along with fixing a host of other discrepancies between browsers and in my opinion gives you a better starting point when authoring CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting this in div.

```
border:none
```

This will remove the border of any element..

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class="headerClear" /></div>
```

see this div has unexpected close the right method is

```
<div class="headerClear"></div>
```

replace with this and add this to your css

```
body{ margin:0px;}
```